# Convert type* to type: cli::array>type,1>^

Tags: c++-cli

I need help converting a parameter of type

```
 double* testVar
```

to a parameter of type

```
 array<double> ^%parentVar.
```

I`m still trying to learn CLI C++ so this might be quite easy but I don't seem to figure it out.

Regards

Comment: You need to copy its content into an `array<double>^`.  Just the raw *testVar* pointer is not enough, you must also know how many elements are in the native array.

Comment: Create `array<double>^` instance, copy `testVar` to it using one of `Marshal::Copy` overloads, and pass it to the function accepting `array<double> ^%parentVar`. When function returns, copy array back to `testVar`.

Comment: Still not able to make it work!

Comment: @Alex can you make a proper answer, your solution works actually i was missing a cast to IntPtr

Comment: Well, for the answer I need to write some code, so let's leave this as tip in the comment...

Comment: Yes but i`m not able to mark your answer as correct.

Comment: No problem. You can post your own answer with actual code and accept it, if you want to keep is as reference for SO users.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on @Alex Farber comment the answer to this question is:

```cpp
double *testVar; // This testVar takes a value from a function that I will not post here
int vectSize = 10;
array<double>^ TempVector= gcnew array<double>(vectSize);
Marshal::Copy(IntPtr(testVar),TempVector,0,vectSize);
parentVar=TempVector;
```

That was all!

Comment: I needed to wait 1 day in order to mark it myself [ And another 3 hours in this moment ]